# snakemake interpreting full path as relative path

Tags: python, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake to perform multiple operations. All the rules, except for the last one (`mvQsubLogs`) work for a test file. This last rule should move the `.e` and `.o` files produced by the `qsub` command (I am running snakemake on a cluster), from the directory specified with the `-e` and `-o` flag, to a directory specified in the output directive of my rule, as soon as some operations are completed (please see `input` directive in the rule below):

```
rule mvQsubLogs:
    input:
        # FastQC
        rules.fastQC.output,

        # Markduplicates
        rules.markDups.output.markDupBam,
        rules.markDups.output.markDupMetrics,

        # mosdepth
        rules.mosdepth.output.DIR,

        # editflagStat
        rules.edit_flagStat.output,

        # edit idxStats
        rules.edit_idxStats.output,

        # insertSizeMetrics
        rules.insertSizeMetrics.output.METRICS,
        rules.insertSizeMetrics.output.PDF

    output:
        directory("{sample}/logs")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {wildcards.sample}/logs " 
        "| mv {LOGDIR}{wildcards.sample}* {output}"
```

A DAG with all jobs that I want to perform can be found below:

[image]

The command that I am using to launch the jobs to the cluster is

```
snakemake -p -s Snakefile_v6_ngs_bngs05b --cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGD
IR} -o {LOGDIR}" -j 5 --use-conda --jobname "{wildcards.sample}.{rule}.{jobid}"
```

Whereas it is important to note where the `.e` and `.o` files should be produced, which for this example is `LOGDIR`. `LOGDIR` was actually retrieved from the config file (`LOGDIR = config['logsOutDir']` - in the snakefile itself and `logsOutDir: "/home/ngs/jobout/"` - specified in the config file).

When I call the full snakemake the command that I get for the rule `mvQsubLogs` is :

```
rule mvQsubLogs:
    input: NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/fastQC, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/aligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.sorted.markDup.bam, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/dups/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.markDups.metrics.txt, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/depth/, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/dups/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.sorted.markDup.flagstat.edited.csv, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/readsDist/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.sorted.markDup.idxstats.edited.csv, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/insertSizeDist/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_ISmetrics.txt, NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/insertSizeDist/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_ISHist.pdf
    output: NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: sample=NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample

mkdir -p NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs | mv /home/ngs/jobout/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample* NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs
```

Which does sound right to me: (after creating the directory to which the files should be moved, just to be on the safe side) I should move all files starting with `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample` (i.e. `wildcards.sample`), located at `/home/ngs/jobout/` to `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs`, whereas this last directory is **relative to the working directory**.

Having a look at the `.e` file generated by the `mvQsubLogs` rule I get:

```
mkdir -p NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs | mv /home/ngs/jobout/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample* NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs
mv: target ‘NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs’ is not a directory
```

Which does not make sense to me, as the output directory `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/logs` should have been created

I have already tried specifying the full path where the files should be moved to, though it did not work either, I got the same error.

Can anyone spot where the error in my code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output} \n" 
        "mv {LOGDIR}{wildcards.sample}* {output}/"
```

Keep the code DRY by using output both times.  That will help if you decide to change the location later.

Replace the pipe with just a second command (the newline).

Add a trailing slash for the second argument to move.  Seems like with nested directories, that is taken as a file if the slash isn't present.  E.g.

```sh
mkdir -p test/log | mv *.out test/log
# mv: target ‘test/log’ is not a directory

mkdir -p test/log | mv *.out test/log/
# ok
```

Comment: it works, thanks very much. You have any explanation as for why it is necessary to create the directory before hand? and why the pipe has to be replaced by the new line?

Comment: Making the directory by hand is part of snakemake, though the docs don't present the reason.  You can use a pipe if you want, but since that's for piping input/output it's not really standard usage; instead `&&` executes the second command if the first succeeds.  Setting as two commands also works.